# Is there any PDF reader app that support keyboard-shortcut customization?

Tags: windows-7, pdf-reader

Which PDF reader have comprehensive keyboard shortcut management (in particular single key shortcut support) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately used AutoHotKey , using following script:

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2

#IfWinActive ahk_class AcrobatSDIWindow
0::Send !vps  ^0 
1::Send ^1 
2::Send !vpc ^2 
r::Send ^h
NumpadAdd:: Send ^{=}
NumpadSub:: Send ^{-}
p:: Send ^+n
s::Send !vps
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html), or if you're looking for a nicer-looking reader and a GUI for shortcut settings, [Okular](http://okular.kde.org/) (but you'll have to [download it with a part of KDE](http://windows.kde.org/)).

## *xpdf* key bindings

- `o` Open a new PDF file via a file requester.
- `r` Reload the current PDF file. Note that Xpdf will reload the file
  automatically (on a page change or redraw) if it has changed since it
  was last loaded.
- `control-L` Redraw the current page.
- `control-W` Close the current window.
- `f` or `control-F` Find a text string.
- `control-G` Find next occurrence.
- `control-P` Print.
- `n` Move to the next page. Scrolls to the top of the page, unless
  scroll lock is turned on.
- `p` Move to the previous page. Scrolls to the top of the page, unless
  scroll lock is turned on.
- `<Space>` or `<PageDown>` or `<Next>` Scroll down on the current page; if
  already at bottom, move to next page.
- `<Backspace>` or `<Delete>` or `<PageUp>` or `<Previous>` Scroll up on the
  current page; if already at top, move to previous page.
- `v` Move forward along the history path.
- `b` Move backward along the history path.
- `<Home>` Scroll to top of current page.
- `<End>` Scroll to bottom of current page.
- `control-<Home>` Scroll to first page of document.
- `control-<End>` Scroll to last page of document.
- `arrows` Scroll the current page.
- `g` Activate the page number text field ("goto page").
- `0` Set the zoom factor to 125%.
- `+` Zoom in (increment the zoom factor by 1).
- `-` Zoom out (decrement the zoom factor by 1).
- `z` Set the zoom factor to 'page' (fit page to window).
- `w` Set the zoom factor to 'width' (fit page width to window).
- `alt-F` Toggle full-screen mode.
- `q` Quit xpdf.

## Adding more key bindings through *xpdfrc*

You can add more key bindings through [*xpdfrc*](http://linux.die.net/man/5/xpdfrc); on Win32 systems, the `xpdfrc` file should be placed in the same directory as the executables.

`bind modifiers-key context command ...` adds a key or mouse button binding

`modifiers` can be zero or more of:

- `shift-`
- `ctrl-`
- `alt-`

`key` can be a regular ASCII character, or any one of:

- `space`
- `tab`
- `return`
- `enter`
- `backspace`
- `insert`
- `delete`
- `home`
- `end`
- `pgup`
- `pgdn`
- `left` / `right` / `up` / `down`        (arrow keys)
- `f1` .. `f35`                       (function keys)
- `mousePress1` .. `mousePress9`      (mouse buttons)
- `mouseRelease1` .. `mouseRelease9`  (mouse buttons)

`context` is either `any` or a comma-separated combination of:

- `fullScreen` / `window`       (full screen mode on/off)
- `continuous` / `singlePage`   (continuous mode on/off)
- `overLink` / `offLink`        (mouse over link or not)
- `scrLockOn` / `scrLockOff`    (scroll lock on/off)

The `context` string can include only one of each pair in the above list.

`command` is an *Xpdf* command (see the COMMANDS section of the [*xpdf*(1) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xpdf) for details). Multiple commands are separated by whitespace.

The `bind` command replaces any existing binding, but only if it was defined for the exact same modifiers, key, and context. All tokens (modifiers, key, context, commands) are case-sensitive.

Example key bindings:

```
# bind ctrl-a in any context to the nextPage
# command
bind ctrl-a any nextPage
# bind uppercase B, when in continuous mode
# with scroll lock on, to the reload command
# followed by the prevPage command
bind B continuous,scrLockOn reload prevPage
```

### Available Commands

The following commands are supported:

- `gotoPage(page)` Go to the specified page.
- `gotoPageNoScroll(page)` Go to the specified page, with the current relative scroll position.
- `gotoDest(dest)` Go to a named destination.
- `gotoLastPage` Go to the last page in the PDF file.
- `gotoLastPageNoScroll` Go to the last page in the PDF file, with the current relative scroll position.
- `nextPage` Go to the next page.
- `nextPageNoScroll` Go to the next page, with the current relative scroll position.
- `prevPage` Go to the previous page.
- `prevPageNoScroll` Go to the previous page, with the current relative scroll position.
- `pageUp` Scroll up by one screenful.
- `pageDown` Scroll down by one screenful.
- `scrollLeft(n)` Scroll left by n pixels.
- `scrollRight(n)` Scroll right by n pixels.
- `scrollUp(n)` Scroll up by n pixels.
- `scrollDown(n)` Scroll down by n pixels.
- `scrollUpPrevPage(n)` Scroll up by n pixels, moving to the previous page if appropriate.
- `scrollDownPrevPage(n)` Scroll down by n pixels, moving to the next page if appropriate.
- `scrollToTopEdge` Scroll to the top edge of the current page, with no horizontal movement.
- `scrollToBottomEdge` Scroll to the bottom edge of the current page, with no horizontal movement.
- `scrollToLeftEdge` Scroll to the left edge of the current page, with no vertical movement.
- `scrollToRightEdge` Scroll to the right edge of the current page, with no vertical movement.
- `scrollToTopLeft` Scroll to the top-left corner of the current page.
- `scrollToBottomRight` Scroll to the bottom-right corner of the current page.
- `goForward` Move forward along the history path.
- `goBackward` Move backward along the history path.
- `zoomPercent(z)` Set the zoom factor to z%.
- `zoomFitPage` Set the zoom factor to fit-page.
- `zoomFitWidth` Set the zoom factor to fit-width.
- `zoomIn` Zoom in - go to the next higher zoom factor.
- `zoomOut` Zoom out - go the next lower zoom factor.
- `continuousMode` Go to continuous view mode.
- `singlePageMode` Go to single-page view mode.
- `toggleContinuousMode` Toggle between continuous and single page view modes.
- `fullScreenMode` Go to full-screen mode.
- `windowMode` Go to window (non-full-screen) mode.
- `toggleFullScreenMode` Toggle between full-screen and window modes.
- `open` Open a PDF file in this window, using the open dialog.
- `openInNewWin` Open a PDF file in a new window, using the open dialog.
- `openFile(file)` Open a specified PDF file in this window.
- `openFileInNewWin(file)` Open a specified PDF file in a new window.
- `openFileAtDest(file,dest)` Open a specified PDF file in this window and go to a named destination.
- `openFileAtDestInNewWin(file,dest)` Open a specified PDF file in a new window and go to a named destination.
- `reload` Reload the current PDF file.
- `redraw` Redraw the window.
- `raise` Raise the window to the front.
- `closeWindow` Close the window.
- `run(external-command-string)` Run an external command. The following escapes are allowed in the command string:

  - %f => PDF file name (or an empty string if no
    file is open)
  - %b => PDF file base name, i.e., file name minus
    the extension (or an empty string if no
    file is open)
  - %u => link URL (or an empty string if not over
    a URL link)
  - %x => selection upper-left x coordinate
    (or 0 if there is no selection)
  - %y => selection upper-left y coordinate
    (or 0 if there is no selection)
  - %X => selection lower-right x coordinate
    (or 0 if there is no selection)
  - %Y => selection lower-right y coordinate
    (or 0 if there is no selection)
  - %% => %
- `openOutline` Open the outline pane.
- `closeOutline` Close the outline pane.
- `toggleOutline` Toggle the outline pane between open and closed.
- `scrollOutlineDown(n)` Scroll the outline down by n increments.
- `scrollOutlineUp(n)` Scroll the outline up by n increments.
- `focusToDocWin` Set the keyboard focus to the main document window.
- `focusToPageNum` Set the keyboard focus to the page number text box.
- `find` Open the 'find' dialog.
- `findNext` Finds the next occurrence of the search string (no dialog).
- `print` Open the 'print' dialog.
- `about` Open the 'about' dialog.
- `quit` Quit from xpdf.

The following commands depend on the current mouse position:

- `startSelection` Start a selection, which will be extended as the mouse moves.
- `endSelection` End a selection.
- `startPan` Start a pan, which will scroll the document as the mouse moves
- `endPan` End a pan.
- `postPopupMenu` Display the popup menu.
- `followLink` Follow a hyperlink (does nothing if the mouse is not over a link).
- `followLinkInNewWin` Follow a hyperlink, opening PDF files in a new window (does nothing if the mouse is not over a link). For links to non-PDF files, this command is identical to followLink.
- `followLinkNoSel` Same as followLink, but does nothing if there is a non-empty selection. (This is useful as a mouse button binding.)
- `followLinkInNewWinNoSel` Same as followLinkInNewWin, but does nothing if there is a non-empty selection. (This is useful as a mouse button binding.)

Answer (score 2):

You should try [Foxit PDF reader](http://products.foxitsoftware.com). When viewing full screen you can press right click  to go next page, left click to go last page. Maybe this is what you mean.

Comment: I need keyboard "customization"!